# How to set class invariants without using conditional if statements

Tags: java, pixel, data-manipulation

I have a class called pixel. I am making a constructor which takes in the red,green,blue,alpha values of a single pixel. How can I have it so that the program only take in valid values for these (e.g. 0 to 255) without using if statements? 
Here is my class below:

```
public class Pixel {
    public int redPix;
    public int bluePix;
    public int greenPix;
    public int alpha;

    public Pixel(int redPix , int bluePix , int greenPix , int alpha) {
        this.redPix = redPix;
        this.bluePix = bluePix;
        this.greenPix = greenPix;
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }


    public void setRed(int redPix) {
        this.redPix = redPix;
    }
    public int getRed() {
        return(redPix);
    }

    public void setBlue(int bluePix) {
        this.bluePix = bluePix;
    }

    public int getBlue() {
        return(bluePix);
    }

    public void setGreen(int greenPix) {
        this.greenPix = greenPix;
    }

    public int getGreen() {
        return(greenPix);
    }

    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public int getAlpha() {
        return(alpha);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    }


}
```

Comment: Why without using conditional statements?

Comment: You need to do something **if** the given value is within the 0..255 interval. That's a condition. You could use ternary operators, but that's essentially a shorter version of `if` statements. I can't really see the reason why avoiding `if`s would be beneficial.

Comment: I also wonder why you want to avoid conditionals, but have you investigated using annotations?  There may be some existing validation annotation libraries, or you could write your own...

Comment: My apologies, I misinformed the question somewhat. I was looking for a shortcut without the use of if statements. Basically, I was wondering if java had something I could import that would be able to check my arguments for me. In theory I could have used if statements but I wanted my code to be easy to read as well.

Comment: @Quinty, the assert statement does this and is recommended practice in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use assertions to specify class invariants. It is actually recommended for private methods.

```
assert x >= 0 && x <= 255;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was not mentioned in my textbook but I will try using this as well!

Comment: Please have a read of these Oracle conventions regarding assertions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/assert-13/index.html

Comment: Also can say that `AssertionError`(which `assert` produces) uses when happened thing that shouldn't have happen. But if client may have access to your code then you should use exception with proper abstraction(like `IllegalArgumentException`).

Answer (score 0):

Likely, best you can do is to write method-helper like this:

```
private void checkArg(int arg) {
        if (arg < 0 || arg > 255) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong argument: " + arg);
        }
    }
```

And then use it in the beginning of all your methods.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try out both answers!